# Is it possible to use non-pixels (e.g., rems, ems) in JavaScript arguments?

Tags: javascript

By default, if I were to write some JS and use a number in an argument, the value would be interpreted as pixels. For example, **"844"** in the if-statement below would be **"844 pixels"**.

```
window.onresize = (function(){
    var w = window.innerWidth, 
        nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

    if (w >= 844 && nav.classList.contains('menu_open')) {
            nav.classList.remove('menu_open');
        }
});
```

Is it possible to specify **ems** or other non-pixel units in this scenario?

Comment: The question I linked to is the first google hit for "javascript window width in ems".

Comment: I was clearly not phrasing my search correctly, haha. Thanks for the link!